# Use the Fitch system to prove the tautology (p ∨ ¬p). Stalled for days (NOT duplicated)

Tags: logic, fitch, tautology

First of all, please don't close this question cause I don't get the explanation given in: [Use the Fitch system to prove the tautology (p ∨ ¬p)](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/42364/use-the-fitch-system-to-prove-the-tautology-p-%e2%88%a8-%c2%acp/72376#72376)

I have been trying to solve this exercise for days now. I'm stuck in step 9:
[image]

Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think that is not a duplicate ? In the linked post there is a Fitch proof: instead of retrying with a new post, why not checking it ?

Comment: You step 4 is the wrong one: use the contradiction with 1 and 3 to derive not-p.

Comment: The explanation Virmaior gives is very unclear and it is 3 years old. I haven't been able to solve it based on his explanation. That's why I need a new input.

Comment: It doesn't work when I try to use the contradiction with 1 and 3 either

Comment: If so, try with the alternative proof provided in the linked answer  p to (p or not-p) (steps 2-3) and p to not-(p or not-p) (from 1) and use the negation-intro rule: if A to B and A to not-B, derive not-A.

Comment: Having derived not-p, you discharge 1 to get : not-(p or not-p) to not-p. Having done so, repeat all the derivation from 1 with the new assumption not-p in 2. In this case you get not-(not-p) and discharge again the assumption to get: not-(p or not-p) to not-(not-p). Now you can apply negation-intro rule (as above) to conclude with not-( not-(p or not-p) ).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to continue from step 11 based on your explanation (I'm a lawyer who signed up for an Introduction to Logic course, could you please explain this to me as if I was 5 years old?) 
1.  ~(p | ~p) Assumption
2. p  Assumption
3. p | ~p Or Introduction: 2
4. p => p | ~p  Implication Introduction: 2, 3
5. p Assumption
6. ~(p | ~p) Reiteration: 1
7. p => ~(p | ~p) Implication Introduction: 5, 6
8. ~p Negation Introduction: 4, 7
9.  ~(p | ~p) => ~p Implication Introduction: 1, 8
10. ~(p | ~p) Assumption
11. ~p Assumption

Comment: Step 12 is same as 3 and 4 will be not-p to (p or not-p). And so on.

Comment: Thank you for all your help Mauro

Answer (score 0):

In step **10**, you need to assume **~(p | ~p)** again, in order to use **Negation Introduction.**

In full:

[image]

Comment: Nevermind, I just fixed it and was able to solve it. MANY THANKS F. Zer! You saved my life today

Comment: You are welcome, @Nagma. Glad it helped.